# Picasso + RecycleView insert image in wrong view

Tags: android, listview, picasso, mixed

I have a simple adapter

```
  public class ConversationListAdapter extends 

            RecyclerView.Adapter<Conversation.ViewHolder> {

                        private List<Conversation> items;
                        private Activity activity;
                        public ConversationListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Conversation>   items) {
                            super();
                            this. items = items;
                            this.activity = activity;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
                            Conversation conversation = mItems.get(i);
                            viewHolder.name.setText(conversation.getName());
                             if ( conversation.getUrl() != null) {                 

         Picasso.with(activity.getApplicationContext()).load(conversation.getUrl())
                                        .into(viewHolder.imageView);
                                 }

                        }

                        and a basic 
                       class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements       View.OnClickListener {..}
                          }
```

Now in the fragment as always:

```
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ConversationAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));
```

Now Im calling my rest api to get the data and the first time it works great everything is where it should be (let's say in c there is only 2 items and the order is conv1 and conv2)

```
private void handleResult(List<Conversation> c) {
items.clear()
items.addAll(c)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

But... now if I refresh for example and the data in the List comes in a different order (conv2 and then conv1) after the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() both of my imageView in the list have the same pictures.. ! But the textView however has the right text

This only happens with view filled with Picasso and cannot understand why

Could someone help me on this ?

Comment: I have just tried and if I remove the null check (i put it because otherwise picasso was putting a blank image) and instead i use .error(..).placeHolder(..) that wrong behaviour doesn't happend

Comment: You defined empty ConversationListAdapter.ViewHolder, but your adapter class typed for Conversation.ViewHolder. What's in there? What do you make in onCreateViewHolder?

Comment: the normal stuff, findById etc..

Answer (score 2):

you use if condition in any adapter you also have to set else part of it. i also don't know exactly why this is happen that if condition is given it takes same condition for child which are not match this, may be a bug in android. please try else part of it also. may be this work for you.

Comment: I can try but I think you might be right, i need to set an else  if I use an if otherwise the viewImage will stay the same as it was before the refresh (even though I used notifiyDataSetChanged with an empty items)

Comment: yes you got the right text because there is no condition with text so its change for every child but in imageview you give condition for few so  child got old one reference and set incorrect image or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace your items in your adapter or create a new adapter with the new items

**1st solution:**

```
private void handleResult(List<Conversation> c) {
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ConversationAdapter(getActivity(), c));
}
```

**2nd solution:**

```
private void handleResult(List<Conversation> c) {
 adapter.setList(c);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And don't to forget to create `setList(List<Conversation> c)` method in your `Adapter`

Comment: yes solution 1 was my temporary workaround but wasn't sure if it was good practice to re set an adapter each time. haven't try solution 2 but the fact that I do items.clear (which is the same items i pass in the constructor) won't this have the same effect as solution 2?

Comment: I use always the second solution but in your case if you want to use the same `items` variable you have to add `adapter.setList(items)` after `items.addAll(c)` because the adapter it keep it's own old ìtems` variable.

Don't forget to accept the answer if it's useful might can help others :)